# How take out the the time from a date table?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I am trying to change date and delete time from a table, but I am getting an error when looking at the table. Here is the original code:

```
select 
cod_contrato as Contrato,
replace (vlr_flat , '.', ',') as Valor_de_Flat,
dth_inicio,
cod_produto,
cod_chassi 
from dbbi.ods.
where vlr_flat >100
and  dth_inicio between '2022-01-01'and current_date 
order by dth_inicio desc;
```

And my table:

| contrato | valor_de_flat | dth_inicio | cod_produto | cod_chassi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000138634 | 2362,15 | 2022-09-30 00:00:00.000 | CCB FIS | 9BRK3AAG3P0071598 |
| 0000138524 | 5982,13 | 2022-09-28 00:00:00.000 | CCB FIS | 9BRK3AAG8P0070821 |
| 0000138429 | 2582,14 | 2022-09-23 00:00:00.000 | CCB JUR | 9BRB33BE3P2128055 |
| 0000138434 | 6032,00 | 2022-09-23 00:00:00.000 | CCB FIS | 9BRB33BE1P2128006 |
| 0000138404 | 6428,18 | 2022-09-22 00:00:00.000 | CCB FIS | 8AJBA3CDXN1735929 |

I have tried the code below to take out (the time) but I keep getting errors:

```
select 
cod_contrato as Contrato,
replace (vlr_flat , '.', ',') as Valor_de_Flat,
dth_inicio,
FORMAT (getdate(dth_inicio), 'dd-MM-yy') as date,
cod_produto,
cod_chassi 
from dbbi.ods.
where vlr_flat >100
and  dth_inicio between '2022-01-01'and current_date 
order by dth_inicio desc;
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: the error I'm having

*"QL Error [42883]: ERROR: function getdate(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."*

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are getting. Please also tag your question with DBMS you are using

Comment: Hint - ```TRUNC()```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  I've never seen the `GETDATE()` function used with an argument.

Comment: @NickW i updated with the error and DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint of using trunc, i cold take out the time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaBKh.png)